# is good to execute automation multiple test cases with one login logout operation?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

As we know with selenium we can execute only Functional and regression test cases.In my application all modules are dependent each others.But i wrote test cases which all are independent(For each test case login/logout operation) and using the existing data.

Comment: You can perform multiple operations with single/multiple logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general answer to this (kind of) broad question. It depends on your testing goals and web application.

**Isolated** test cases tend to

- be more stable
- have less dependencies
- execute slower
- be more redundant
- produce more test code
- increase need to modularise

For **comprehensive** tests the opposite is true. For some use cases (like CRUD scenarios) a comprehensive test case is probably the most natural approach.

So, in the end you may choose which characteristics are suitable for your situation.